# Application resize speed vs resize speed in visual studio designer 2012

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, visual-studio-2012

I have an application in c# winforms. I'm trying to resize it, and that does work but really slow. I see the window refreshing for like 5 seconds before it finishes loading.

On my window I have a tablelayoutpanel, which holds a few buttons and one control. this control again holds several buttons and controls.

When I resize the same window, in the designer, the speed is not very very fast, but acceptable.

How can the designer be so much faster than the actual application?

Any tips/tricks how to increase the resizing speed? I've once found something about increasing speed when switching between forms. These tricks did not really help in this situation.

**EDIT** I've found that the background image is slowing the whole application when resizing... so I've to figure out how to make this quicker.

Comment: Because the designer doesn't execute code while resizing your form. Should be something you are doing when resizing or some other long execution operation running.

Comment: My code is not doing anything at all..

Comment: A lower quality background image may help.